# Apparent memory leak when using PyTuple_SetItem

Tags: reference-counting, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I'm building a nested set of tuples in a C++ Python extension.  However, I'm having some problems with managing reference counts.

The minimal code to re-create this memory leak:

```
PyObject *outer = PyTuple_New(outer_size);
for (size_t index = 0; index < outer_size; ++index) {
    PyObject *inner = Py_BuildValue("iiiiiiiiid", ...);
    PyTuple_SetItem(outer, index, inner);
}
Py_CLEAR(outer);
Py_INCREF(Py_None);
return Py_None;
```

Now, if I instead replace the `PyTuple_SetItem(outer, index, inner)` with a `Py_CLEAR(inner)`, the memory usage doesn't grow over time.

Am I wrong about the outer tuple stealing the reference to the inner tuple?  Is there some other reason memory wouldn't be reclaimed?

Comment: The code should not leak. I'd add asserts liberally to check the return value of each API function and show the code hiding behind the `...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was mistaking a very slowly growing memory usage (for other reasons) for a memory leak. Had the reference counting been failing, it would have grown substantially faster. So, it's true. This code doesn't leak.

Comment: In case this is a bit confusing...  the code was returning a set of windows detected in an image.  It turns out that the list of images I was using just happened to have more windows in each image, therefore using more memory over time.